# Transfer database from Red Hat Linux to WAMMP

Tags: mysql, redhat, database, file-transfer

I've currently got a MySQL 5.X database on a server running Red Hat Linux 4 (from memory), which I currently shell into with Putty.
I now need to replicate the server in WAMP for offline debugging, and need to transfer the database over.

I've tried researching it, but everywhere says to just 'copy the files over' (and I CAN stop the MySQL service), but I'm not exactly sure how to do this in the shell (I DO have root access) and it feels... "icky".

Is there a recommended procedure / protocol for doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to copy your environment to your WAMP server you should dump your database and restore it [in accordance with the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.6/en/using-mysqldump.html) (this is for 5.6, but you can easily find the same page for other versions).

As a note for the future, your first stop for research should ***ALWAYS*** be the documentation for the product you're using (in this case, [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index.html)).
At least half of the information out there on the internet is written by blithering idiots -- trust the documentation from the people who wrote the software. It's correct far more frequently.